# Custom validation message for Invalid Data Type Input | Spring Validation

Tags: spring-boot, validation, spring-validation

I am working with sprinboot in a simple web application, I using the spring validation framework to validate my fields constraints.

I have a "version" field that its a float, when I enter strings for example my binding result throws this message at the html:

> Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.lang.Float for property version; For input string: "StringTemplate"

Ive tried the rejectValue in the controller but it always show first the default message and then my custom one.

> Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.lang.Float for property version; For input string: "StringTemplate"
> Version must be a number

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be custom properties. There you can parse your values manually and handle the errors. see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-property-editor